# Scrapy + sqlalchemy + mysql error

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, scrapy

and i am building a web crawler for personal use.

Here is the Spider file

[image: scrapySpider]

Here is the model file

[image: model]

Here is the pipe line

[image: pipeline]

My database settings are

```
DATABASE = {'drivername': 'mysql+mysqldb',
        'host': 'localhost',
        'port': '3306',
        'username': 'user', # fill in your username here
        'password': 'pass', # fill in your password here
        'database': 'scrapydb'}
```

**But i am getting this error**

```
  .............., line 19, in process_item
  vehicle = vehicles(**item)
  exceptions.TypeError: vehicles() got an unexpected keyword argument 'odometer'
```

I've tried many things but was unsuccessful. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vehicles` should be a `class`, not a function:

```
class vehicles(DeclarativeBase):
    ...
```